# Attributes nodeName of elements become lowerCase automatically

Tags: javascript, html

Why any nodeName of attribute in attributes property of element becomes lowercase, and how make it camelCase?

I have a following code:

```
<div myAttr = "true"></div>
<script>
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
var attr = div.attributes[0];
console.log(attr.nodeName);
</script>
```

this will display myattr, but in markup was myAttr, why? and how fix it?

Comment: attributes are lowercase in html5. you can use html4 if attrib case  is important to you.

Comment: or any flavour of XHTML (though you are supposed to namespace any non-standard attribute you want to use there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code has to be lowercase: This applies to HTML element names, attributes, attribute values (unless text/CDATA), CSS selectors, properties, and property values (with the exception of strings).

Please refer this link:
https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Capitalization

Comment: That is incorrect. HTML doesn't *have to* be lowercase. It's *recommended* (because HTML is case-insensitive and normalised to lowercase anyway). Your answer doesn't even attempt to explain the behaviour observed by OP.

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#syntax-attribute-name):

> […] In the HTML syntax, attribute names, even those for foreign
>   elements, may be written with any mix of lower- and uppercase letters
>   that are an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's name.

There's a similar section about tag names, too, if you follow the link and scroll up a little.

So, what happens is that the HTML parser doesn't care what mix of case you use for your attribute name. I couldn't find somewhere that says precisely that custom attributes must be normalised to lowercase by the DOM ([this is the most relevant bit](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#namednodemap)), but since the matching *must* be case-insensitive, why not. Note that if you try this with your mixed case:

```
div.getAttribute('myAttr')
```

it will return the expected value, even though internally the attribute name is 'myattr'. Then again, this will do the same thing:

```
div.getAttribute('MYattR')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old school solution from someone who started as a B-developer (and Originally trained on A as in APL-360)

```
    static void ChangeNodeNamesToLower(XmlDocument dom)
    {
        if (dom == null) return;
        char[] sampleXML = dom.DocumentElement.OuterXml.ToCharArray();
        bool inquote=false;
        for(var i=0; i<sampleXML.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sampleXML[i]=='"') inquote= !inquote;
            if(!inquote) {
                sampleXML[i] =Char.ToLower( sampleXML[i]);
            }
        }
        dom.LoadXml(new string(sampleXML));           
    }
```